# eclipse compiler compiles code that javac will not - code looks to be legal

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-stream

The following code compiles in Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600 on Windows 10 Version 10.0.14393. It does not compile on a range of oracle javac compilers. There are other questions concerning pieces of code that compile with the Eclipse JDT compiler, but not javac. I could not find one similar to this example. This is a piece of toy code, and it's only purpose is to demonstrate this curiosity.

Is the eclipse compiler correct to compile this?

Note: If the eclipse compiler generated .class is de-compiled it produces source which can be compiled with javac.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Puzzle {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List> outer = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object()), 
                                         Arrays.asList(), 
                                         Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object()));

        Stream<Boolean> bs1 = outer.stream().flatMap(inner -> inner.stream()).map(obj -> obj.hashCode() % 2 == 0);
        boolean b0 = bs1.filter(b -> !b).findAny().isPresent();

        boolean b2 = outer.stream().flatMap(inner->inner.stream())
                            .map(obj -> obj.hashCode() % 2 == 0)
                            .filter(b ->  !b).findAny().isPresent();

        System.out.printf("%s %s %s", outer, b0, b2);
    }
}
```

Here is the compiler error, in several versions of the compiler:

```
C:\Users\tofti>C:\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac -version & C:\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac Puzzle.java
javac 1.8.0_121
Puzzle.java:23: error: bad operand type Object for unary operator '!'
                            .filter(b -> !b).findAny().isPresent();
                                     ^
1 error

C:\Users\tofti>C:\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\javac -version & C:\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\javac Puzzle.java
javac 1.8.0_112
Puzzle.java:23: error: bad operand type Object for unary operator '!'
                            .filter(b -> !b).findAny().isPresent();
                                     ^
1 error

C:\Users\tofti>C:\jdk1.8.0_141\bin\javac -version & C:\jdk1.8.0_141\bin\javac Puzzle.java
javac 1.8.0_141
Puzzle.java:23: error: bad operand type Object for unary operator '!'
                            .filter(b -> !b).findAny().isPresent();
                                     ^
1 error
```

And here is the code compiling, and executing in Eclipse:
[Code compiling and running in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2skRs.png)

Comment: Looks like an Eclipse bug. Doesn't compile for me in 4.6.3 build 20170314-1500.

Comment: @shmosel I am asking the reverse. The code compiles in Eclipse, but not javac. Is there a bug in javac, and the particular version of the eclipse compiler is correct? Or, is javac correct to not compile this code? And why?

Comment: I understood. My point is it's probably an Eclipse bug that was fixed already. Or do you have a later version?

Comment: It "works" in later versions of eclipse, i.e. like javac it does not compile. Should this code compile? If not, why not? @shmosel

Comment: If both compilers reject it, it probably should not compile. As to why, the rules governing type inference are extremely complex. Feel free to read up on it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html

Comment: Interestingly, only the second lambda (the one in the longer chain, for `b2`) triggers a compiler error on my OpenJDK 8u144 javac.

Comment: Yes, there is only one error in javac. From a types perspective, how are the two pieces of code different? The one longer statement, and the two shorter ones? I included the two variants to highlight the curiosity.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that the multiple errors in your compiler output were the same single error on different compiler versions.

Comment: Another way to make the code compile by giving the compiler an extra hint about the type of the lambda is to change the `filter` call to `filter((Predicate<Boolean>)(b -> !b))`. My knowledge of the JLS is insufficient to answer whether the compiler _should_ be able to figure things out without this additional information.

Comment: I revised the question to make it clear there is one error, and it appears in several versions of the compiler tested.

Comment: You can also do (b->!((boolean)b)), but I would think this should compile directly, without the extra hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the suppressed "unchecked" warnings reveals the problem, in Eclipse 4.6.3:

```
Type safety: The expression of type Stream needs unchecked conversion to conform to Stream<Boolean>
```

And in javac 1.8.0_131:

```
Puzzle.java:12: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        Stream<Boolean> bs1 = outer.stream().flatMap(inner -> inner.stre
am()).map(obj -> obj.hashCode() % 2 == 0);

     ^
  required: Stream<Boolean>
  found:    Stream
```

Without any casting, here are the actual return types from each method call in the chain:

```
Stream<List> s1 = outer.stream();
Stream s2 = s1.flatMap(inner -> inner.stream());
Stream s3 = s2.map(obj -> obj.hashCode() % 2 == 0);
Stream s4 = s3.filter(b -> !b); // compiler error
Optional opt = s4.findAny();
boolean b = opt.isPresent();
```

If you add a wildcard to make it `List<List<?>> outer`, this is what you get instead:

```
Stream<List<?>> s1 = outer.stream();
Stream<?> s2 = s1.flatMap(inner -> inner.stream());
Stream<Boolean> s3 = s2.map(obj -> obj.hashCode() % 2 == 0);
Stream<Boolean> s4 = s3.filter(b -> !b); // compiles OK
Optional<Boolean> opt = s4.findAny();
boolean b = opt.isPresent();
```

So the issue is that the `.map` call on the raw `Stream` doesn't actually return `Stream<Boolean>`, you're just implicitly casting it when you assign `bs1`, and that fixes the raw types in the rest of the chain. In fact, you can add this cast to the one-line version and it compiles:

```
boolean b2 = ((Stream<Boolean>) outer.stream().flatMap(inner -> inner.stream())
        .map(obj -> obj.hashCode() % 2 == 0))
        .filter(b -> !b).findAny().isPresent();
```

Now, the raw `.map` call is missing the class type parameter `<T>`, but `<R>` is a method type parameter, so why doesn't it return `Stream<R>`? The [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) section in the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html) states that "a non-static type member of a raw type is considered raw". The example given is a generic inner class, but assuming it applies to generic methods as well, this should be the reason for the `<R>` parameter of `.map` getting dropped when it's called on a raw `Stream`, causing it to return another raw `Stream`.

EDIT: Found this in [an Eclipse bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473657#c6):

> It looks like javac infers the return type of the method invocation to be the raw type I when passed in arguments are raw types. This may be motivated by the almost last bit of [§18.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2) after bounds set 4 has been generated
>
> [...]
>
> **If unchecked conversion was necessary** for the method to be applicable during constraint set reduction in §18.5.1, then the parameter types of the invocation type of m are obtained by applying θ' to the parameter types of m's type, and **the return type** and thrown types of the invocation type of m are **given by the erasure of the return type** and thrown types of m's type.

Comment: Thank you, @sean-van-gorder. I wasn't aware of the implicit cast which allows assignment to Stream<Boolean> (adding types in to the stream, as you point out)   
    `Stream<Boolean> bstream = outer.stream().flatMap(inner -> inner.stream()).map(obj -> obj.hashCode() % 2 == 0);`

And it is evident when you remove the generic typing, as you highlight. 

Under the eclipse compiler:
    `Stream bstream2 = outer.stream().flatMap(inner -> inner.stream()).map(obj -> obj.hashCode() % 2 == 0);`

the map function is still considered to return Stream<Boolean>.

Comment: It seems this was fixed in Eclipse 4.6 (Neon), possibly as a side-effect of fixing [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473657), so the warning might not appear in 4.5. I'm seeing the warning and the compiler error in both Eclipse 4.6.3 and javac 1.8.0_131.